# Remove all sub id's when removing main id

Tags: php, mysql

I might explain this wrong but here goes. I want to create a folder system from a MySql Database.

Folder 1
  ---Sub Folder 1
  ---Sub Folder 2
  ---Sub Folder 3
    ----Sub Sub Folder 1
    ----Sub Sub folder 2
etc.

Now this is all loaded in my MySql Database as follows:
[image]

Now lets say I want to Delete ID 2 (which is Folder 2), but under Folder 2 is ID 7 (Testing 1) and under that folder is ID 8 (Testing 2). So in folder tree view it would look like this: Folder 2/Testing 1/Testing 2

My question is how would I write a PHP/MySql script to remove everything that falls under ID 2 without having to replicate my MySql code 3 time to remove everything? (And there might be more folders in each folder and sub folders that needs to be removed, but they all fall under ID 2)

Thank you in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY COLUMN `child` INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`child`) REFERENCES `table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Mysql is an **R**DBMS. Use the R of that word (relational), it's made for that.

The `DELETE CASCADE` clause will do that when the parent is deleted, all children are as well, recursively. But it also means that you can't add a child if the parent does not exist yet so you might have to change your business process.

Comment: With the info you gave me, I think I'm still a big noob in MySql hahaha. Now then how do I add data (folders) as I see that the id does not auto increment?

Comment: No sorry it can be autoincrement, no problem! I changed the description. I didn't know you had this attribute on that column. @DevExpert